# Filling a table in code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if there could be an easier or simpler way of filling a table with code behind.

So far I have my **html/asp.net** table :

```html
<table style="width:275px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsH0" runat="server" Text="Section"></asp:Label></th>
            <th><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsH1" runat="server" Text="Capacity Push (lbf)"></asp:Label></th>
            <th><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsH2" runat="server" Text="Capacity Pull (lbf)"></asp:Label></th>
            <th><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsH3" runat="server" Text="Stroke (in)"></asp:Label></th>
            <th><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsH4" runat="server" Text="Outside diameter (in)"></asp:Label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage0Text" runat="server" Text="Master"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage0Value0" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage0Value1" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage0Value2" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage0Value3" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage1Text" runat="server" Text="1st stage"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage1Value0" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage1Value1" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage1Value2" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage1Value3" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage2Text" runat="server" Text="2nd stage"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage2Value0" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage2Value1" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage2Value2" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage2Value3" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage3Text" runat="server" Text="3rd stage"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage3Value0" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage3Value1" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage3Value2" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage3Value3" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage4Text" runat="server" Text="4th stage"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage4Value0" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage4Value1" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage4Value2" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBL_StatsStage4Value3" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my CodeBehind :

```vb
LBL_StatsStage0Value0.Text = "--"
LBL_StatsStage1Value0.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePush(1))
LBL_StatsStage2Value0.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePush(2))
LBL_StatsStage3Value0.Text = "--"
LBL_StatsStage4Value0.Text = "--"

LBL_StatsStage0Value1.Text = "--"
LBL_StatsStage1Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(2))
LBL_StatsStage2Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(2))
LBL_StatsStage3Value1.Text = "--"
LBL_StatsStage4Value1.Text = "--"

LBL_StatsStage0Value2.Text = "--"
LBL_StatsStage1Value2.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadLength(1) - cylinderLoadLength(0))
LBL_StatsStage2Value2.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadLength(2) - cylinderLoadLength(1))
LBL_StatsStage3Value2.Text = "--"
LBL_StatsStage4Value2.Text = "--"

LBL_StatsStage0Value3.Text = cylinderOutsideDiameter(0)

If UBound(cylinderLoadForcePush) > 2 AndAlso cylinderSectionStroke(3) <> 0 Then
    LBL_StatsStage3Value0.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePush(3))
    LBL_StatsStage1Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(3))
    LBL_StatsStage2Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(3))
    LBL_StatsStage3Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(3))
    LBL_StatsStage3Value2.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadLength(3) - cylinderLoadLength(2))
    If UBound(cylinderLoadForcePush) > 3 AndAlso cylinderSectionStroke(4) <> 0 Then
        LBL_StatsStage4Value0.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePush(4))
        LBL_StatsStage1Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(4))
        LBL_StatsStage2Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(4))
        LBL_StatsStage3Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(4))
        LBL_StatsStage4Value1.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadForcePull(4))
        LBL_StatsStage4Value2.Text = Math.Round(cylinderLoadLength(4) - cylinderLoadLength(3))
    End If
End If
```

As you notice, I have hardcoded line by line every cell. I have also made the name of my cells incremented to make them easier to find or use.

### Question

How can I make this code simpler or how can I shorten it? Is there a way that I could implement a `For Loop` that loops through every cell of the table and adds the proper value to it?

Comment: It looks a lot like you could use a [Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295084.aspx), but I have no VS handy right now so I can't put code together...

Comment: @Vogel612 Interesting, I read through the documentation of `ASP:Repeater`. It says that it needs a template.. As this is the only table I have in my website, wouldn't that take even more lines?

Comment: How that? Your template is one `<tr>/*stuff between*/</tr>`. This could drastically shorten your code to simply providing the correct collection to the repeater and do nothing more.

Comment: @Vogel612 Oh okay! Nevermind, I misunderstood the documentation, that will indeed drastically shorten my asp.net/html code! Thanks for that. Any thoughts on how I could shorten my CodeBehind(VB)?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use an `<asp:GridView />`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2s019wc0(v=vs.100).aspx

In your code behind you can set the DataSource property and the call DataBind

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="fooGrid" />
```

And in C#:

```
fooGrid.DataSource = // some array or IEnumerable or DataTable
fooGrid.DataBind();
```

There are many more tags and attributes you need to set on the grid view element. See the link above for examples.